# How to find if a customer was contacted thrice over a period of two days?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find out a list of mobiles who have been contacted thrice over a period of two days using columns like mobile and call_time?

From my understanding, I have tried using below code, by using self-join it will match similar mobile numbers and I need to find out if a mobile repeated thrice or more but I also need to find out difference between the maximum and minimum call time for a particular customer to see if it is less than two days. **Do let me know how to implement that logic:**

```
select c1.mobile
from call_Records c1, call_Records c2
where c1.mobile=c2.mobile and max(call_time)-min(call_time)<=2
```

I would want data to be like:

Customer Mobile

XXXXX0001

XXXXX0002

XXXXX0003

Comment: What datatype is `call_time`?

Comment: provide some sample data

Comment: datetime format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should give you the results you want. It does a self-join based on the same mobile being called within 2 days of the original call, and then counts the number of rows, only returning those with 3 or more calls within 2 days.

```
SELECT c1.mobile, c1.call_time
FROM call_Records c1
JOIN call_Records c2 ON c2.mobile = c1.mobile
WHERE c2.call_time >= c1.call_time - INTERVAL 2 DAY AND c2.call_time < c1.call_time
GROUP BY c1.mobile, c1.call_time
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for this. I am validating your code. Is it necessary to have the call_time in select as well as group by, cause it's returning a lot of duplicate records. Will it affect the logic if it was removed?

Comment: @rameshkumar you need to include `call_time` in the `GROUP BY` so that the query only counts calls made within 2 days of that particular `call_time`. If you are getting too many duplicates from each mobile number, you could wrap the entire query in `SELECT DISTINCT mobile FROM (...) c`